# MSVC error C2971 for const wchar_t * as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I want to add some information about parameters in my program (type and convertation function). Name of parameters is const. I wrote some code for it, but it not compile in MSVC 2017 (on GCC or Clang is OK)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace params
{
    constexpr wchar_t CLIENT_LOGIN[] = L"ClientLogin";

    template<const wchar_t * ParamName>
    struct convert_traits
    {
    };

    template<>
    struct convert_traits<CLIENT_LOGIN>
    {
        using ConvertType = unsigned long long;
        static ConvertType convert(const std::wstring &str) 
        {
            return std::stoull(str);
        }
    };
}

int main() {

    std::cout << params::convert_traits<params::CLIENT_LOGIN>::convert(L"123.0") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I receive errors:

```
main.cpp(15): error C2971: 'params::convert_traits': template parameter 'ParamName': 'params::CLIENT_LOGIN': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument
main.cpp(10): note: see declaration of 'params::convert_traits'
main.cpp(6): note: see declaration of 'params::CLIENT_LOGIN'
main.cpp(26): error C2971: 'params::convert_traits': template parameter 'ParamName': 'params::CLIENT_LOGIN': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument
main.cpp(10): note: see declaration of 'params::convert_traits'
main.cpp(6): note: see declaration of 'params::CLIENT_LOGIN'
```

and can't found a fix for MSVC.

Comment: The variable is at namespace scope - so is of static storage duration.

Comment: I had hoped that this was the difference between ` template<const wchar_t* ParamName>` and ` template<const wchar_t ParamName[]>` - but [@Rook](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1450890/rook) says the latter fails too :-(

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
extern const wchar_t CLIENT_LOGIN[] = L"ClientLogin";
```

but not work if define it in header.